# Drupal in view query add new join table and remove old table

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal 7 is there any way that i can alter join table field value in query of view

```
LEFT JOIN {draggableviews_structure} draggableviews_structure
    ON node.nid = draggableviews_structure.entity_id
        AND draggableviews_structure.view_name = 'homepage_views' 
        AND draggableviews_structure.view_display = 'panel_pane_12' 
        AND draggableviews_structure.args = '[\"1\"]'
```

From above query of left join table I want to change `draggableviews_structure.args` field value `'[\"1\"]'`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you implement the Drupal hook `hook_views_query_alter()` which allows you to alter the query before its executed. You can check this [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) for more info on this hook.

The actual implementation should look like this:

```
<?php    
/**
     * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
     */
    function your_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
      dpm($query->table_queue['draggableviews_structure']['join']);
    }
?>
```

The `dpm()` should print the join part of the query that you need to modify and should allow you to modify the value of `draggableviews_structure.args`